# LEFT OUTER JOIN with DATEDIFF in Hive QL

Tags: sql, database-design, join, hive, hiveql

I have two tables: let us call them INSTALLS and EXECUTES.

INSTALLS table has the structure: user_id BIGINT, install_ts BIGINT.

EXECUTES table has the same structure: user_id BIGINT, exec_ts BIGINT.

The user_id is obvious, the _ts fields are timestamps expressed as seconds counted from Unix epoch.

These two tables get populated like this:

Every time a user installs my application, the INSTALLS table is populated. He could then uninstall and reinstall, in which case another row for the same user appears in this table (different ts, though). For all my analysis, I need to use the oldest installation timestamp.

Every time a user uses my application, the EXECUTES table is populated - with the user_id and the time of execution.

I need to create a summary table with this structure:

date, count of installs on that date, count of usage on subsequent date

This is how I approached the problem:

1. Get oldest installation date:

   SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id
2. Get dates of execution (need to cater for multiple executions in a given date):

   SELECT user_id, DATE(exec_ts) AS exec_date FROM EXECUTES GROUP BY user_id, DATE(exec_ts)
3. Combine these two:

   SELECT a.install_date, COUNT(a.user_id) AS install_count, COUNT(b.user_id) AS usage_count
   FROM
       (SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id) a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT user_id, DATE(exec_ts) AS exec_date FROM EXECUTES GROUP BY user_id, DATE(exec_ts)) b
       ON a.user_id = b.user_id
   GROUP BY a.install_date

This will count all users who used my application anytime. From this dataset, I now need to extract only those users who used my application on the immediately subsequent date of their installation date.

One approach I considered was to have an additional JOIN condition. When I do that, I get (query first, error below that):

```
SELECT a.install_date, COUNT(a.user_id) AS install_count, COUNT(b.user_id) AS usage_count
FROM
    (SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, DATE(exec_ts) AS exec_date FROM EXECUTES GROUP BY user_id, DATE(exec_ts)) b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id AND DATEDIFF(b.exec_date, a.install_date) = 1
GROUP BY a.install_date
```

> Both left and right aliases encountered in JOIN '1'

The second approach I considered was to have the DATEDIFF in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT a.install_date, COUNT(a.user_id) AS install_count, COUNT(b.user_id) AS usage_count
FROM
    (SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT user_id, DATE(exec_ts) AS exec_date FROM EXECUTES GROUP BY user_id, DATE(exec_ts)) b
    ON a.user_id = b.user_id
WHERE b.user_id IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(b.exec_date, a.install_date) = 1
GROUP BY a.install_date
```

But I can see that this is simply wrong - if a user installs on day 1 and returns on day 3, he will not be counted in install_count (since he will not be present in the joined table). So now I am sort of out of ideas. I am a bit of a novice to SQL, so any assistance would be really appreciated.

Comment: check out this solution using ROW_NUMBER - http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?1669663-help-with-query-using-min-datediff

Answer (score 2):

If I understand completely, the result rows will contain a date, the number of installs by *unique users* on the date, and the count of the number of times the program was executed on the day after an installation *across all users*.. so, there are 2 different calculations for each date.

My solution starts with a join of the two tables (without the grouping you used) and then subsequent operations use the analytics functions and then group. In my testing, the tables used string types, so dates look like "2013-08-01", etc and DATEDIFF can be used.

I created an intermediate join result table, but this could easily be rolled up into the final query. This join table will contain a row for each user with an install date and a 1 or 0 to indicate if there was an execute on the next day.

```
create table i_e_join as
select i.user_id, i.install_ts,
       if (e.exec_ts is null OR (DATEDIFF(e.exec_ts,i.install_ts) > 1), 0,1)
         over (partition by i.user_id,i.install_ts) as has_exec
from tmp_installs i left outer join tmp_executes e on (i.user_id = e.user_id);
```

and then a simple group by to get the result for each install_ts:

```
select install_ts, count(distinct user_id) as install_count, 
       sum(has_exec) as usage_count from i_e_join
group by install_ts;
```

The key for creating the join table is using the analytic function to calculate the has_exec field which looks across all the rows from the user on the install_ts.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this myself. This is how I did it:

```
SELECT x.install_date, COUNT(x.user_id) AS install_count, COUNT(y.user_id) AS usage_count
FROM (
    SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id
) x LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT a.user_id AS user_id, a.install_date AS install_date, b.exec_date AS exec_date
    FROM
        (SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(install_ts)) AS install_date FROM INSTALLS GROUP BY user_id) a
        JOIN
        (SELECT user_id, DATE(exec_ts) AS exec_date FROM EXECUTES GROUP BY user_id, DATE(exec_ts)) b
        ON a.user_id = b.user_id
        WHERE DATEDIFF(b.exec_date, a.install_date) = 1
) y
GROUP BY x.install_date
```